# blackberry arabic text

Tags: blackberry, arabic

In my application, i need to show some english and arabic text in a `net.rim.device.api.ui.component.EditField`. The text comes from server encoded with UTF-8. @ iPhone it is works fine but on BB we see small black filled rectangles instead of Arabic text.

I do not want to enforce users to download some font to see the text. I need embedded solution.

I am developing for BB OS 4.5.

Comment: Do like this if you are using the eclipse: RightClick on "ProjectName"-->properties-->Resource-->Text file encoding-->click on "Other" radio button and select "UTF-8";

Comment: But i am getting the text from server, and it is encoded with UTF-8.

Comment: Getting what ever you can store in String; but when your paste in coding part and also show in device;

Comment: Since you're targeting OS 4.5, have you checked whether Arabic is supported on BlackBerry OS 4.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely a font issue. In OS 5+ you can ship your app with a custom font that supports Arabic and install it at run time. Instructions and sample code for how to do this can be found in [this development guide topic](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Load_and_use_a_custom_font_899948_11.jsp).

Unfortunately, there is any support for custom fonts pre-5.0 (see, e.g., [this thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Using-a-TTF-Font-in-your-Blackberry-Application/td-p/465668)).

Comment: Thanks for instant reply! But there is no FontManager on OS 4.5

Comment: @AhmetGulden Yep. I think that the only thing you can do is to ask users to install a language pack that supports Arabic. See [this knowledge base article](http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB13067) for more info.